# GKRTree return all elements found overlapped with the specified bounding region?

Tags: ios, swift, mapkit

I'm trying to do this by using `GKRTree` in `GameKit`. What I did:

1. Parsing data from GeoJson
2. Add all polygons (MKPolygon) to an GKRTree
3. In `regionDidChangeAnimated` delegate function, get all visible polygons from the `GKRTree` by using `elements` query.

Based on Apple's document, `elements` query will return:

> An array of objects stored in the tree whose bounding regions overlap the specified region. The array is empty if no such objects are found.

But unfortunately, this is not the case. This query will only return the objects ***contained*** instead of ***overlap*** the specified region.

My code:

```
    // loading from GeoJson
    self.rtree = GKRTree<MKPolygon>(maxNumberOfChildren: 5)
    self.polygons = polygons
    polygons.forEach({ polygon in
      if let overlay = polygon.mapShape() as? MKPolygon {

        let rect = overlay.boundingMapRect

        let vecMin = vector_float2([Float(rect.minX),Float(rect.minY)])
        let vecMax = vector_float2([Float(rect.maxX), Float(rect.maxY)])

        self.rtree?.addElement(overlay, boundingRectMin: vecMin, boundingRectMax: vecMax, splitStrategy: GKRTreeSplitStrategy.linear)
      }
    })


func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, regionDidChangeAnimated animated: Bool) {
    if let rtree = self.rtree {
      let rect = mapView.visibleMapRect
      let vecMin = vector_float2([Float(rect.minX),Float(rect.minY)])
      let vecMax = vector_float2([Float(rect.maxX), Float(rect.maxY)])

      let all = rtree.elements(inBoundingRectMin: vecMin, rectMax: vecMax)
      //print(all)

      mapView.removeOverlays(mapView.overlays)
      var overlays = [MKPolygon]()
      for polygon in all {
        overlays.append(polygon)
      }
      self.mapView.addOverlays(overlays)
    }
```

Please refer to my screenshots:

[image]

[image]

Any idea? Thanks.